# Billiards/Pool Table Sounds

Tags: sound-effects, sound

I was wondering if anyone has or know any sound libraries that consists of Billiards and/or Pool Table sounds? I can't find any anywhere so that is why I am asking. -Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Plenty on [Freesound.org](https://freesound.org/) if you don't mind a little scanning! Quality varies... Licenses under Public Domain and/or Creative Commons.

Search results:

[Billiard](http://www.freesound.org/search/?q=billiard)

[Pool Table](http://www.freesound.org/search/?q=pool%20table&f=&s=score%20desc&advanced=0&g=1)

[Snooker](http://www.freesound.org/search/?q=snooker&f=&s=score%20desc&advanced=0&g=1)